# Can we create Bean and an object using new keyword at the same time?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, dependency-injection

```
public class UserInterface{
public static void main(String args[]){

ApplicationContext applicationContext = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(SpringConfig.class);

AbcClass abc = applicationContext.getBean(AbcClassImpl.class); 

AbcClass cde = new AbcClassImpl();
}
}
```

Just wanted to know if it is possible to create using new keyword if we have already created Bean for that.

Comment: You can. but if you creating the object via `new` keyword, autowiering doens't work in it. If you need more than one instace of a bean you should take a look at the prototype scope

Comment: @Jens Thanks, Got it. Yeah That's why I was getting the NullPointerException when I was trying to access methods of Autowired Class using "cde" Object.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can, however the custom instantiated object will lack the injection or dependence injection which spring provides to a bean.

Certainly, it is advisable to conform to the framework's principles. That is, avoid manual intantiation of "beans".

Comment: Yeah Got it. I was just trying if we can create using new keyword also and will it have the full functionality. But was getting NullpointerException when I was trying to access methods of Autowired Class using "cde" Object. Thanks !!